# How to set default selected options in magento product detail page

Tags: magento

I have requirement in which i am getting product ID from external Application with product super_attribute options like color,size. I am getting all those and i can do the add to cart option.

But here my actual requirement is to select the requested options by customer and redirect them to product detail page in magento so that here they can still enter optional text to print. So i need to set the requested options in detail page and redirect them to product detail page instead of adding it to cart. They will enter more details and then they will do addtocart manually.

How can i set the selected options while loading itself.

Please help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thankfully this is already built in to most themes. You need to know the ID of both attributes and values from the Simple product that is included in the Configurable product. I've only seen it work with Configurable types so that might be a limitation.

- For each attribute make a key=value pair
- Combine the attributes as a query string, eg. "123=345&678=890"
- Append the string as a *hash fragment* (not as a query).
  This is an example from the official demo, note that the first option needs to be selected for the second to work so it has two key/value pairs.

  > http://demo.magentocommerce.com/zolof-the-rock-and-roll-destroyer-lol-cat-t-shirt-126.html#525=99&272=22

Comment: But i do have problem on product custom options. When i use # to set the default options as like following **#965=167&966=170&967=187** it worked perfectly. And when i do the same thing for product Custom options as follows **56=263&55=260&52=252** it is not working. How can i set the default options for custom drop downs instead of Attribute based drop downs.

Comment: You can see the script that initialises the fields in `js/varien/product.js`. Look for where it reads `window.location` and you can see it is only for configurable products. You might have to mimic that to make your own initialiser script for simple products.

Comment: How can I show default selected options on product page for configurable product, based on the layered navigation filters selection on list page?

Comment: Muk's question is really good and I hope he finds an answer. If anyone is following then he asked it here also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18572765/471559

Answer (score 1):

Rough Magento2 example add the below for pre-selecting the custom options by name=value in:

```
/www/mysite/app/design/frontend/mycompany/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/options.phtml
```

The below code looks at the label of the option and the text value of the select. And depends on your theme structure. Example below for Luma.

It expects the following format in the url

```
product.html?SelectLabel=OptionValue&SelectLabel=OptionValue
```

This does not account for multi language etc.. you could easily adapt it to instead look for the select id and option id which would be more accurate replacing

```
$(label).parents().eq(1).find('select option:contains('+arr[k]+')').attr('selected', true);
```

with (untested)

```
$("#"+k+" option[id='"+arr[k]+"']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

```js
<script>
        require(['jquery'],function($){

            $(document).ready(function(){

                function getJsonFromUrl() {
                    var query = location.search.substr(1);
                    var result = {};
                    query.split("&").forEach(function(part) {
                        var item = part.split("=");
                        result[item[0]] = decodeURIComponent(item[1]);
                    });
                    return result;
                }
                var arr = getJsonFromUrl();
                for (var k in arr){
                    if (arr.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                        //alert("Key is " + k + ", value is" + arr[k]);
                        var label = $('.product-options-wrapper').find("span:contains('"+k+"')");
                        $(label).parents().eq(1).find('select option:contains('+arr[k]+')').attr('selected', true);

                    }
                }

            });

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Yup, this works in Magento 2, with a query string just as described above: `produc-url?OptionTextLael=OptionNumericValue`